# Anyway to check if my github repo link given is right or not without any commit or adding files

Tags: python, git, github

I am making a cli based application where the user requires to add his github repo link before proceeding forward.
The one question that may arise to you is why didnt u ask in  the last  , after adding all the changes .
The problem is if user adds his data and since I am not saving it to any of the data base , it will directly be added to folder and this folder will be commited later on , so if it happens that the url is wrong then the user will have to write the whole data again which I dont want .
one thing that came into my mind is using a PUT api call on the git repo and if it generates a 200 status that would mean that the  repo link is right and user can proceed forward , else vice versa
But that would also require a Personal access token which I don't want .

I can reframe my question if you don't understand.

I tried using Personal Access token but now I feel that every other user cant make use , if I send this application to a client how come he will add Personal access token and why will he give me his PAT just for an application

Comment: You won't be able to connect to a private repo without authentication - that's kind of the point of authentication.

Comment: Not checking for Private repos just for Public ones

Comment: In that case, you'll still need authentication for pushing commits, but `git ls-remote $URL` will return either a list of refs or an error.

Comment: I feel I can use this list of ref data to verify,or put a condition that if no error is found then my git url is right.Is this how it can work??